# AWS Lambda/SNS Publish ignore invalid endpoints

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, boto3

i'm sending apple push notifications via AWS SNS via Lambda with Boto3 and Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('sns')
    for record in event['Records']:
        if record['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
            rec = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']
            competitors = rec['competitors']['L']
            for competitor in competitors:
                if competitor['M']['confirmed']['BOOL'] == False:
                    endpoints = competitor['M']['endpoints']['L']
                    for endpoint in endpoints: 
                        print(endpoint['S'])
                        response = client.publish(
                            #TopicArn='string',
                            TargetArn = endpoint['S'],
                            Message = 'test message'
                            #Subject='string',
                            #MessageStructure='string',
                        )
```

Everything works fine! But when an endpoint is invalid for some reason (at the moment this happens everytime i run a development build on my device, since i get a different endpoint then. This will be either not found or deactivated.) the Lambda function fails and gets called all over again. In this particular case if for example the second endpoint fails it will send the push over and over again to endpoint 1 to infinity.

Is it possible to ignore invalid endpoints and just keep going with the function?

Thank you

Edit:

Thanks to your help i was able to solve it with:

```
try:
    response = client.publish(
        #TopicArn='string',
        TargetArn = endpoint['S'],
        Message = 'test message'
        #Subject='string',
        #MessageStructure='string',
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```

Comment: BTW, it would be better to move the creation of the boto3 SNS client outside of your handler.  That way, you don't have to create a new client each time the handler is called.

Comment: Hey garnaat! Thanks a lot for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aws lamdba on failure retries the function till the event expires from the stream.

In your case since the exception on the 2nd endpoint is not handled, the retry mechanism ensures the reexecution of post to the first endpoint.

If you handle the exception and ensure the function successfully ends even when there is a failure, then the retries will not happen.

Comment: Hello Shibashis,
thanks for your help. I will try this!